# Transform child out of bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know what's wrong with my code. The first case that is spawned works correctly, but after that a get the error message "Transform child out of bounds". That's because only the first element is being considered. The objects are spawned by the one called "Spawner" and the script "Mandibula" is attached to them.

I tryed to put a loop, but it doesn't work. How could I fix that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Alavanca : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Pegar o player pra impedir ele de largar algum item na bancada
    private PlayerController Player;
    //Pegar a mandibula pra poder acionar a contagem dos espaços
    private Mandibula Mandibula;
    //pegar o spawner, pra poder pegar a bancada pelo seu filho
    private GameObject Spawner;

    void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        Spawner = GameObject.FindWithTag("Spawner");
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
        {
            Player.PodeLargar = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Spawner.transform.childCount; i++)
                {
                    Mandibula = Spawner.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Mandibula>();
                     Mandibula.Contar_Espaços();

                }
            }
            catch
            {

                print("Ainda não tem caso");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
        {
            Player.PodeLargar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

*[Added from the delted answer]*

The method `Contar_Espaços` is in the script `Mandibula`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Mandibula : MonoBehaviour
{
    //define o número de espaços
    public ValidadorEspaço1[] espaços;

    //variável para acessar o script do gamecontroller
    private GameController gameController;
    private GameObject controller;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Controller");
        //acessa o script GameContoller
        gameController = controller.GetComponent<GameController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Contar_Espaços()
    {
        gameController.contadorPontos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
        {
            if (espaços[i].DenteCerto)
            {
                gameController.contadorPontos++;//se os dentes e grampos são colocados no lugar certo, o contador incrementa
            }
        }

        if (gameController.contadorPontos == 14)
        {
            //se o jogador colocar todos os dentes e grampos nos lugares corretos, ele soma 1 ponto
            gameController.CasosResolvidos++;
            //após somar um ponto, a mandíbula é destruída para que outra seja spawnada no lugar dela
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact text of the error you are reading in the logs, as well as the line of code referenced in the error.  For example, if your error looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcKop.png) then we would need to see what line of code was on line 63 of Trigger.cs.

Comment: Um brasileiro aqui... que nem o Ruzihm mencionou acima, inclua o erro ocorrido pra te ajudarmos

Comment: @Nícolas this community is in English.

Comment: i'm sorry, its because the owner of this post is Brazilian, as i am

Answer (score 1):

In a former post we could see that you have a

```
if (gameController.contadorPontos == 14)
{
    //se o jogador colocar todos os dentes e grampos nos lugares corretos, ele soma 1 ponto
    gameController.CasosResolvidos++;

    //após somar um ponto, a mandíbula é destruída para que outra seja spawnada no lugar dela
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

in your `Contar_Espaços()`.

If you think about it: The moment you destroy a child object obviously the `childCount` from before becomes invalid and so does your iteration variable `i` since it now can reach an index where no child can be found anymore.

---

I'ld recommend as alternative to rather give your method a `bool` as return type like

```
public bool Contar_Espaços()
{
    gameController.contadorPontos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
    {
        if (espaços[i].DenteCerto)
        {
            //se os dentes e grampos são colocados no lugar certo, o contador incrementa
            gameController.contadorPontos++;
        }
    }

    if (gameController.contadorPontos == 14)
    {
        //se o jogador colocar todos os dentes e grampos nos lugares corretos, ele soma 1 ponto
        gameController.CasosResolvidos++;

        //após somar um ponto, a mandíbula é destruída para que outra seja spawnada no lugar dela
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and now rather collect all elements that return `true` and destroy them later e.g. using [Linq Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where):

```
using System.Lynq;

...

if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
{
    var todestroy = Spawner.GetComponentsInChildren<Mandibula>(true).Where(m => m.Contar_Espaços());
    foreach(var mand in todestroy) 
    {
        Destroy(mand.gameObject);
    }   
}
```

this is a shorthand for writing

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
{
    var todestroy = new List<Mandibula>();

    // gets all Mandibula references from this and any child object
    // (add parameter true for also getting currently disabled or inactive ones)
    var mandibulas = Spawner.GetComponentsInChildren<Mandibula>(true);

    foreach(var m in mandibulas)
    {
        if(m.Contar_Espaços()) todestroy.Add(m);
    }

    foreach(var mand in todestroy) 
    {
        Destroy(mand.gameObject);
    }   
}
```

---

In general please have in mind that this community (like all other StackExchange communities) is in **English** so either remove the comments or translate them to English so they are of use for us as well. You should get used to code and comment in English always. It is **the** global coding language ;)

Comment: Hi, I've already solve the problem. The spawner object was wrong. Now, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using GetComponentsInChildren

```
...

if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && other.tag == "PlayerCollider")
{
    var mandibulas = Spawner.GetComponentsInChildren<Mandibula>();
    foreach(Mandibula mand in mandibulas) 
    {
        mand.Contar_Espaços();
    }   
}

...
```